# Windows 7 starts blank after booting into Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu

I have a Thinkpad W520 with a dual boot arrangement using BootIt BM. One partition has Windows 7, the other has Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. Problem: Booted Windows fine, went to Ubuntu, booted just fine, shut down and booted to Windows...says "Starting Windows"...and it stops at a black screen, does not display the Welcome screen. I see just the mouse which I can move. Sleep command works, on resume it goes back to the black screen. To use Windows again I must cold shutdown, reboot in safe mode, and reinstall the Intel graphics driver. Then a shutdown and reboot and all is fine. Till I boot into Ubuntu again and attempt to return to Windows.
I have looked at closely similar questions here but am unable to find the same issue as described here. What could be happening? Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you install Ubuntu properly?

Comment: I believe so because I have been using this Ubuntu installation without any issues for 3 months now.